# Modular forms defined on the modular curve

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms, moduli-space

I am studying the book "Harmonic maass forms and mock modular forms theory and applications"

In section 7.5, they deal with p-adic harmonic maass functions.

At first, they define the space $M_k(\Gamma_0(N);K)$

This is the space of weight k holomorphic and weakly holomorphic modular forms defined on the  modular curve $Y_0(N)(K)$ over the field K.

I have difficulty understanding this definition.

What is $Y_0(N)(K)$? (I only know the basic stuffs for modular curve)

What is modular forms on this modular curve? (I'm familar with the classical modular forms)

Is there any reference to understand this definition?

Do I need to know the language of schemes?

Comment: A weight $2$ classical modular form $f$ on $X_0(N)_\Bbb{C}$ is such that $f(z)dz$ is a $1$-form (invariant by the action of $\Gamma_0(N)$) so that $f(z)dz = h \, d j$ where $h$ is an element of the function field and $j$ is the $j$-invariant. A weight $4$ modular form will be an element of $M_2 \otimes_{\Bbb{C}(X_0(N))} M_2$ with no poles, where $M_2$ are the weight 2 modular forms with poles. This algebraic formulation translates well to modular curves over other fields.

Comment: @reuns Thank you very much!